# Extract np.array from dict in each row of pd data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I managed to store dicts in each row of a column of a pd.dataframe.
Is there a way without a for loop to extract np.arrays from a specific key in each of the dicts at once, please?

My mini-example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d={}
d['key1']=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
d['key2']=np.array([1,2,3,4])                     
d['key3']='Mexico'

df=pd.DataFrame( index=[0,1,2,3,4,5],columns=['A'])

df.loc[0,'A'] = [d]
df.loc[1,'A'] = [d]
df.loc[2,'A'] = [d]
df.loc[3,'A'] = [d]
df.loc[4,'A'] = [d]
df.loc[5,'A'] = [d]

df

df.loc[[1,2,3],'A']
```

With `df.loc[[1,2,3],'A']` I am able to select multiple rows, hence multiple dicts, but I am blocked to access 'key2' for each of them, for example.
Is there a way to extract data from 'key2' for all selected rows at once without looping, please? Thank you.

Edit:
Avoiding the `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series` when trying to place a dict without wrapping into an element of a dataframe, can be achieved with `.at`.
The example would be then extended by

```
df.at[0,'B'] = d
df.at[1,'B'] = d
df.at[2,'B'] = d
df.at[3,'B'] = d
df.at[4,'B'] = d
df.at[5,'B'] = d

df
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked to access 'key2'". What did you do? Which error did you get? And why do you wrap each element into a list?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "blocked to access 'key2'" - I meant that I cannot make the next step. I figured out in the meantime that maybe the apply method could work. 
Re wrapping: see below. I got an error if I don't do this.

Comment: `dict` have to be accessed individually.  Thus looping is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].apply(lambda x: x[0]["key2"])

1    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2    [1, 2, 3, 4]
3    [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, some code suggestions:

1. Dont use `dict` as a variable name, use `d` instead. `dict` is an inbuilt function in python.
2. You should use a dict of lists, then you can set each column in the data frame to a key in the dictionary:

```
d={}
d['key1']=[np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])]
d['key2']=[np.array([1,2,3,4])]                     
d['key3']=['Mexico']
```

Then you can create a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

and the columns will be the keys of the dictionary:

```
                     key1          key2    key3
0  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  Mexico
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement your suggestions. I renamed the `dict` to `d`. I created my df with `df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3,4,5],columns=['A'])`, but when I do `df.loc[0,'A'] = d` with the dict from the example (now called `d` and each item is not a list), I get `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series`. I think this is why I put the dictionary within a list.

Comment: I have also another question, please. Regarding the `apply` method using a lambda function, isn't this indirectly somehow looping, please? But I learned now how to use the apply-method. applymap would not work because it only expects single scalars as result, please? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Sorry yes you are right. I have deleted that part of my answer. Using `df.apply` is not the same as looping over the rows of the dataframe. `apply` is a lot faster as pandas is able to use optimized c code to perform the operations. It is not *always* the fastest way to perform the operation, but a lot of the time it is the simplest, most readable and plently quick enough.

Comment: Thank you. The first code section is the most helpful. I understand with `x[0]` one accesses the first element of the list that is the dictionary. Via the key I obtain the value. Now I have to figure out why this does not work for my real word example :-)

The second part is good to know. Currently, I just don't see why I should create a new df, when I have one and just want to extract a np.array from each dictionary in each row from one column. I apologise, if I don't see this. But many thanks for your help.

Comment: My impression from other SO is that dataframe `apply` is pretty slow, especially with a generic function.  It may with selected operations apply its own compiled methods, but it isn't going to compile your Python code.  There is a `raw` parameter that tells it to work with numpy arrays directly.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. My mini-example had in each df element a list containing a dict. If I try to store it as dict and not as list, I get this error earlier mentioned.
 But my real example has in each element of the pd.df a dict, no error is generated. There I am confused. I will figure it out.

Comment: @hpaulj: I understand only little what you say, because I am not advanced. But after having thought a while today about this problem, I can see what is the advantage of Tom McLean's suggestion. Instead of storing a dict, maybe add the 10 keys of the dict as new columns to the data frame. Accessing a np.array from an element in a column would be easier than jumping into the column, the element of the df, and then into the dict.